# AngularJS: What is difference between ng-options and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular.i have seen people use `ng-options and ng-repeat` both to populate drop down. i have seen also people generate tabular data or generate `ul/li` related data with `ng-repeat`.

i like to know what is difference between **ng-options and ng-repeat ?**

here i am putting to set of code and both populate dropdown. in first case **ng-option** is used and in second case **ng-repeat** has been used. hence i am new in angular so do not understand the difference between **ng-options and ng-repeat ?**

also tell me in what kind of scenario people can use ng-options rather use ng-repeat.

### 1st of code

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <select ng-options="r.countryId as r.name for r in chooseCountries" ng-model="selectedCountry">
    </select>
</div>

var app = angular.module('main', []);
    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.chooseCountries = [
            { countryId: 0, name: "Select Account", desc: "some description" },
            { countryId: 1, name: "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" },
            { countryId: 2, name: "Gibraltar", desc: "some description" },
            { countryId: 3, name: "Malta", desc: "some description" }
        ];

        $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.chooseCountries[2].countryId;
    });
```

### 2nd of code

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
  <select ng-model="selectedCountry">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
          <option ng-repeat="x in chooseCountries" ng-value="x.countryId"  >{{x.name}}</option>
</select>  
</div>

var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chooseCountries=[
        {countryId : 1, name : "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" },
        {countryId : 2, name : "Gibraltar", desc: "some description"},
        {countryId : 3, name : "Malta", desc: "some description"}
    ];
 $scope.selectedCountry =  $scope.chooseCountries[1].name;   
});
```

so tell me where we can use **ng-option** and where we can not. also tell me where **ng-repeat** will be applicable only.

another one question that how could i specify column name when using ng-repeat.....is it possible?

see this code `ng-repeat="x in chooseCountries"` if my object has so many fields then all will be loaded in x but how could i specify one few column or field name.

Comment: The bigger difference is `ng-options` has ability to bind `object` to `ng-model` where as `ng-repeat` on `option` tag will provide ability to bind `string` value to `ng-model`. You could readup on doc.. there they have mentioned with great example.

Comment: Just read the official documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: not very clear the difference. so anyone can explain with sample code which discuss the difference by example. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The biggest difference between the two can be found under the docs for ngOptions: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

ngOptions should be used when possible per the docs:

- provides memory benefits increasing speed by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
- provides more flexibility in how the select's model is assigned
- allows for binding of non-string values to the model

So in summary, the ngOptions directive is more flexible and more efficient and ngRepeat should be avoided for options

Comment: can u tell me in what kind of scenario ngOptions will not be right choice or may not be able to produce output?

Comment: can we use ngOptions to populate a html table where people often use ng-repeat or ngOptions only use to populate dropdown ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar I haven't ever encountered a scenario requiring a ngRepeat. I believe the idea behind ngOption was to address the negative impacts of ngRepeat and extend functionality for use for use with select menus. If you have a particular scenario you can't figure out, post another question and I'm sure someone can implement with ngOptions. Per your second question, ngOptions is a directive for select menus (options), not table entities.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-options` is a specialized variant of `ng-repeat`.

`ng-options` exists specifically to populate `<select>` lists with `<options>`.

`ng-repeat` is for more general use, like you would use `forEach` in Javascript or `for user in userlist` in Python.